# How to share image in google Plus through an android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus

I have already tried this code, but i didn't saw photo shared in my account.

```
File file = new File("sdcard/1346249742258.jpg");
String photoUri = null;
photoUri = file.getAbsolutePath();

Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
        .setText("Sharing an image on Google!").setType("image/jpeg")
        .setStream(Uri.parse(photoUri)).getIntent()
        .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: when application starts it shows a toast having a message "you can only post photos presents on your sd-card only". but i am giving the address of photo from sd-card. what is the problem i am not understanding?

Comment: @DeepikaLalra I have similar problem. Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrate ForGooglePlus Activity in your code and put URL(imageUrl) ,Description(description text) and contentUrl(URL) for the same.
Note : bellow code also worked in my app.

```
public class ForGooglePlus extends Activity
{
    private String imageUrl, description, contentUrl;
    private Context mContext;
    private int REQUEST_FOR_GOOGLE_PLUS = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mContext = this;
        imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("URL");
        description = getIntent().getStringExtra("Description");
        contentUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("contentUrl");

        if (isPackageInstalled("com.google.android.apps.plus", mContext)) {
            if (imageUrl == null) {
                imageUrl = "";
            }
            if (description == null) {
                description = "";
            }
            // Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
            // .setType("image/jpeg")
            // .setText(description)
            // .setStream(getUriFromUrl(imageUrl))
            // .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(contentUrl))
            // .getIntent();

            Uri uri = getUriFromUrl(imageUrl);
            if (uri != null) {
                Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
                        .from(ForGooglePlus.this)
                        .setText(description + "\n" + contentUrl)
                        .setType("image/jpeg").setStream(uri).getIntent()
                        .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
                startActivityForResult(shareIntent, REQUEST_FOR_GOOGLE_PLUS);
            } else {
                Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
                        .from(ForGooglePlus.this)
                        .setText(description + "\n" + contentUrl)
                        .setType("image/jpeg").getIntent()
                        .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
                startActivityForResult(shareIntent, REQUEST_FOR_GOOGLE_PLUS);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Application not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    public Uri getUriFromUrl(String thisUrl) {
        try {

            Bitmap inImage = ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync(thisUrl);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            String path = Images.Media.insertImage(
                    mContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
            return Uri.parse(path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return true;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_FOR_GOOGLE_PLUS) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        mContext.getString(R.string.msg_gp_cancel),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 26):

The Google+ app only supports [content:// URIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html). You will need to use the `MediaStore` API for this purpose.

```
 File tmpFile = new File("/path/to/image");
 final String photoUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
         getContentResolver(), tmpFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, null);

 Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
         .setText("Hello from Google+!")
         .setType("image/jpeg")
         .setStream(Uri.parse(photoUri))
         .getIntent()
         .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
```

Comment: it gives me FileNotFoundException(). because it is not getting full path of image it is taking only "sdcard/1346249742258.jpg".

Comment: For this we need Google+ installed on device correct as its using intent. I don't want to use the Intent, can we do it programmatically. Here is my question on SO..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955084/share-photo-on-google-plus-using-android-sdk-not-by-share-intent

Answer (score 3):

I am also posting image on google plus through android using intent i am taking screen shot of device and posting it on google plus, i used your code i am getting exception FileNotFoundException() and as you mention to use absolute path i got error,
The method getAbsolutePath() is undefined for the type String
my code is given below 
please suggest me correction in code

```
    package com.testproject;


    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    public class TestProjectActivity extends Activity {

        private Button share_btn = null; 
        private String url=null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            share_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share_btn);
            share_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent=new Intent(TestProjectActivity.this,ShareDialogActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);    
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);  
                }
            });
        }
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            String url =takeScreenShot();
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (resultCode) {
            case 1:
                String share = data.getExtras().getString("NAME");
                if(share!=null && share.equalsIgnoreCase("Share with Instagram")){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.setType("image/jpg");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share Image"));
                }

                if(share!=null && share.equalsIgnoreCase("Share with GooglePlus")){
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    File tmpFile = new File(url);
                    String photoUri=null;
                    photoUri = url.getAbsolutePath();
                    try {
                        photoUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                                getContentResolver(), tmpFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, null);
                        shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                        .setText("Hello from Google+!")
                        .setType("image/jpeg")
                        .setStream(Uri.parse(photoUri))
                        .getIntent()
                        .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
                        startActivity(shareIntent);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        public String takeScreenShot(){
            try{
                RelativeLayout  view = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.icflag_layout);
                View v1 = view.getRootView();
                System.out.println("Root View : "+v1);
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
                url =MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bm,"screeshot.jpg", 1233+ ".jpg Card Image");
            }
            catch(OutOfMemoryError e){

            }
            return url;
        }
    }
```

Thank you and regards
Nitin

Answer (score 1):

Don't use absolute path.

OnActivityResult() use this after capturing image from camera.

```
Uri photoUri = intent.getData();                
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                         .setText("Hello From Google+!")
                             .setType("image/jpeg")
                             .setStream(photoUri)
                             .getIntent()
                     .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

HEy Deepika you are getting file nor found exception because that google plus app is not present on the device the way you have coded is just to start the native app from the device

it will work only if the native ap is actully present

otherway is to have google plus sdk which is small jar file with that you can share image

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/

Answer (score 0):

You can share image using below api's. For detailed steps check tutorial

http://androidsrc.net/integrating-google-plus-sign-in-into-your-android-application/

```
 /**
     * API to process media post request start activity with MIME type as video
     * and image
     */
    private void processShareMedia() {
        Intent photoPicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPicker.setType("video/*, image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPicker, PICK_MEDIA_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

/**
 * Handle results for your startActivityForResult() calls. Use requestCode
 * to differentiate.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_MEDIA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // If picking media is success, create share post using
        // PlusShare.Builder
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
            String mime = cr.getType(selectedImage);

            PlusShare.Builder share = new PlusShare.Builder(this);
            share.setText("Hello from AndroidSRC.net");
            share.addStream(selectedImage);
            share.setType(mime);
            startActivityForResult(share.getIntent(),
                    SHARE_MEDIA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}
```