# Get object File from a file in raw folder

Tags: android, android-resources

What i want to do is very simple :

```
    String dataDir = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getActivity().getPackageName(), 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;

    Log.e(TAG , "dataDir = " + dataDir);

    File tmpFile = new File(dataDir + "/raw/ocr.jpg");
```

But i got a file not found exception

i NEED an object file as after i do

```
    photoUriString = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), tmpFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, null);
```

(because i want to share the picture on google+, see [How to share image in google Plus through an android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891382/how-to-share-image-in-google-plus-through-an-android-app))

So please don't tell me about a reader, a bufferedReader, etc ...

Thanks

Comment: You can access a raw resource like R.raw.ocr

Comment: u can get the particular resources id.using this int resID = ApplictionName.this.getResources().getIdentifier(yourFileName,"raw",ApplicationName.this.getPackageName());

Comment: I need the absolute path of the file. Please read my post :(

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ocr.jpg));
```

you have to get the InputStream through `openRawResource`, then you can manage it as you need

Comment: I need a File object. Not stream, because i can't get the absolute path from a stream object.

Comment: copy the stream inside your sdcard and the take the path to the file. It is the only way