# Try to share picture on google+ but i got "could not attach all media items to the post"

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus

I want to share a picture on google, it should be easy but it is not :-(

```
    File rootSdDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File pictureFile = new File(rootSdDirectory, "attachment.jpg");

    Log.e(TAG , "pictureFile.absolutePath = " + pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Log.e(TAG , "pictureFile.length = " + pictureFile.length());

Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);

Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(getActivity())
                    .setText("Hello from Google+!").setType("image/jpeg")
                    .setStream(pictureUri).getIntent()
                    .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
            startActivity(shareIntent);
```

The intent is started, the text is there, but not the picture. And a toast from android system appears saying : "could not attach all media items to the post"

When i search this error message on google i only found this :

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=31442

Is anyone has a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Google+ app only supports content:// URIs. You will need to use the MediaStore API for this purpose. An example could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12943954/2366413).